# Is there a quick way to clear a large amount of data from a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the need to clear all data (except row 1) from two sheets in the same workbook. Currently one sheet has 21,000 rows and the other has 10,000 rows, both have 26 columns.

When I use the following code it takes approximately 2.5 minutes to execute.

There must be a faster way to do this as I can do it manually in less than 8 seconds.

```
Sub DeleteExceptFirst()
TurnOffFunctionality           'Turn off at the start
    Dim StartTime As Double
        StartTime = Timer         'Get start time
        
    Dim shCount As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    
    For shCount = 1 To 2
        If shCount = 1 Then
            Set wks = cnCustomers
        Else
            Set wks = cnVendors
        End If
    
    wks.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Next shCount

TurnOnFunctionality            'Turn back on at the end
Call EndTimer("DeleteExceptFirst", StartTime)
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this: `wks.usedrange.offset(1).clearcontents`

Comment: N.B. Delete is different from ClearContents.

Comment: Approximately 2.5 minutes? Strange result. For me, your procedure on different data was executed several times faster than a second. Perhaps internal errors have accumulated in this workbook? Sometimes it helps to resave the workbook several times by changing the format, for example, xlsm->xlsb->xlsm

Comment: Do you have formulas that need to be recalculated? How long does a regular recalc of the sheet take? Write a time stamp into a cell between each of your code steps and then you can see which of the code steps takes so long. If it is after the loop, then the recalc is the problem and you need to look at the formulas in your file. Inefficient formulas can bring a workbook to a screeching halt.

Comment: How much time does `wks.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Delete` take?

Comment: Siddhartha Rout  ".Delete" was somewhat faster, taking 1min 50 seconds.

Comment: Hooded_One your code was much better, taking only 59 seconds. Thanx

Comment: JohnSUN  - I'l try your suggestion. Thanx

teylyn - No formulas to recalculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I incorporated AcsErno's line into a simple loop for you.

```
Sub deleteallbutfirstrow()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents

Next

starting_ws.Activate 'activate the worksheet that was originally active

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting over the *whole* range size including all columns, but restricting deletion to **contents** only.
As anything right of column Z may contain a whole bunch of blanks, extra formatting etc., VBA has a lot to do separating cell informations.

A simple way to provide for faster code execution might be to mark the entire columns block
from column AA to XFD manually and to delete them completely.
In a second step you can limit the pure content deletion to the 26 columns needed, e.g. via

```
            Dim header: header = wks.Range("A1:Z1")
            wks.Range("A:Z").ClearContents
            wks.Range("A1:Z1") = header
```

or alternatively to execute a *complete clearing* - not restricted to contents only - plus eventual (number/date) reformatting of the whole columns `A:Z`.

*Of course a damaged workbook as mentioned by @JohnSUN in comment may cause most issues, so follow his advice then* :-)